# cakephp contain filtering by parent model value

Tags: cakephp

I have these relations:

Attendance belongs to Employee

Schedule belongs to Employee

This find() works just fine to get all Attendance records in a date range.

```
    $data = $this->Attendance->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'Employee' => array(
                'Schedule' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('sche_status' => 1),
                    'order' => 'sche_valid DESC',
                    'limit' => 1
            ))
        ),
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => array('employee_id', 'att_date')
            )
    );
```

However, this Schedule condition

```
'conditions' => array('sche_status' => 1),
```

gets the "current" Schedule. Problem is when Employee has more than one Schedule in the date range.
In order to get the relevant Schedule for it's parent Attendance record, I need to also 
condition on Attendance.att_date

Tried

```
'conditions' => array('sche_status' => 1, 'ho_valid <=' => Attendance.att_date)
```

and

```
'conditions' => array('sche_status' => 1, 'ho_valid <=' => $this->Attendance.att_date)
```

How can I reference Attendance.att_date from the contan Schedule conditions? Is that possible? 
My current datasets are pretty clean and my find() is dry, wouldn't want to make a mess here.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `contain()`, it does individual queries. In your example, it will actually do three queries individually that then get combined by CakePHP into the returned data array.

So, you cannot use fields from a different model to condition against a contained model.

Your best bet is to either query the field first, then use it's value in this find, or use [joins()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables), which makes all the results return from a single query instead of three separate queries.

Side note - it appears you're building this query in a Controller - following the MVC structure, best practice is to keep ALL queries in your Model, not your Controller - then just call the Model's method (which has the `find()`) from the Controller to retrieve the results.

Comment: Thank you @Dave; haven't used cake joins yet; will re-evaluate my needs in this case.  Best regards.